# If cell equals a certain value, automatically return whatever is in the cell 2 columns over in the same row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking for help with creating a formula. If a cell equals a certain value, how do I return whatever is in the cell 2 columns over in the same row? For example, if A=VALUE, Return C from the same row. In the example posted, this would mean:

- If A=24, return -23.57%
- If A=25, return 7.48%
- If A=26, return 7.83%

I want to apply this to an entire columns.

[image: Example]

Comment: VLOOKUP function will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `VLOOKUP` to do this.

For example, if the value you call "A" is in cell E1, and the table of data in your example is in range A1:C6, you can use the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(E1, A1:C6, 3, FALSE)
```

This searches the first column of data (column A) for the value in cell E1 and returns the corresponding value from the third column (column C).

`FALSE` as the fourth argument says to only look for an exact match. If you use `TRUE` instead, your data must be sorted on the value in the first column and the function will search for the closest value.